# Add imageview to layout on specific coordinates

Tags: java, android, layout

I am dynamically adding ImageViews to layout. Here is the code, which is doing what I want:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    ImageView smokeImage = new ImageView(this);
    Drawable smoke = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smoke);
    smokeImage.setBackgroundDrawable(smoke);
    main.addView(smokeImage, 800, 800);
```

How to add ImageView to specific coordinates? For example. I want it to appear on x=25px and y=43px . Are there any special functions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set margins to your image view. You can use create `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, set margins to params

```
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

and set params to your image view

```
smokeImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```